# Capistrano bundler not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, setup-deployment

but the bundler is already on the server installed, this shows me the.

```
gem list
```

shows me the bundler 1.0.22, and on my local machine it shows after gem list

```
bundler (1.1.1, 10.22)
```

I don't know where the second came from. I tried this tutorial http://teachmetocode.com/screencasts/basic-deployment-with-capistrano/ but i get an error like this.

```
 Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [bigdecimal-1.1.0, io-console-0.3, json-1.5.4, minitest-2.5.1, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.9.4] (Gem::LoadError)
```

Where are this errors from?

Comment: how did you installed ruby? please include output of `gem env`

Comment: I installed it like the rvm ruby tutorial.
https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/
There are no Problems lacally it runs, but deployement makes my cry :-)

Comment: i removed the command in the Capfile from the line
`load 'deploy/assets'`

Comment: `RubyGems Environment:`
`- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.15`
`- RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-02-16 patchlevel 125) [x86_64-linux]`
`- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125`
`- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby'
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin`
`- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:`
`- ruby`
`- x86_64-linux'`
`- /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125`
`- /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global`
`- :update_sources => true`
`- :verbose => true`
`- :benchmark => false`
`- :backtrace => false`
`- :bulk_threshold => 1000`

Comment: check my latest article for working tutorial of capistrano with rvm,bundler,rails... -> http://niczsoft.com/2012/03/fast-deployment-using-capistrano-rvm-and-more/

Comment: Thanks, i checked, it doesn't run. Our config we using Apache with passagner. I don't know why it does'nt run.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that you need to create the bundler wrapper. You can do that this way(in your deploy.rb, for example)

```
require "rvm/capistrano" # http://beginrescueend.com/integration/capistrano/

# rvm-capistrano settings
set :rvm_ruby_string, ENV['GEM_HOME'].gsub(/.*\//,"")

namespace :rvm do
  task :create_bundle_wrapper, roles: :app do
    run "rvm wrapper #{rvm_ruby_string} bundle bundle"
  end  
end

after "deploy:create_symlink", "rvm:create_bundle_wrapper"
```

Comment: Hi...you've posted the same answer three times. If you're doing this then there's a fairly good chance all three questions are dupes, so flag them as such instead. If these aren't exact dupes then please address the specifics of the question rather than posting the same copy-paste answer. Thanks.